# Restore volume groups after remove in RO file sytem

Tags: lvm, encryption, qubes

I wanted to transfer all my data from encrypted HDD to Qubes OS

1. I attach HDD and run these commands:

   ```
   udisksctl unlock -b /dev/xvdi5   

   modprobe dm-mod 

   vgscan

   vgchange -ay debian-vg
   ```
2. After I copied a couple of file i run this:

   ```
   lvchange -an debian-vg

   vgremove debian-vg
   ```

Now i have this error:

```
Begin: Runing /scripts/local-block ...
Volume group "debian-vg" not found 
Skipping volume group debian-vg
Unable to find LVM volume debian-vg/root
```

In `/etc/lvm` is only one file (lvm.conf)

Maybe somewhere in the logs left data about LVM volume or volume group?

Comment: What do `vgs` and `lvs` say? Maybe those scripts are run a bit too late, after the actual removal? Does your problem only relate to this error message? Was your copy successful?

Comment: On the disk was installed encrypted debian
I turned off qube and run from the first disk